# LocalStorage not being saved (Vanilla JS)?

Tags: javascript, css

I'm new here (and coding, in general) but everyone says that once you have a question and you are unable to find the answer in Stackoverflow, you should ask, but I've always found that maybe the question was too dumb.

The thing is, I was trying to set a switcher for light-dark mode and it works fine, but once you refreshed the page, the theme change was not being saved. I found that using JavaScript you can store that change locally by using "localStorage.setItem()", but it's not working as I expected. I will try to provide as many details as I can:

- I have created two css classes for my body tag: 'dark' and 'light', each one with its own css variables for colors. Note: I do not have two body tags, it is just to show both classes I have to toggle between.

```
<body class='light'>(all the content)</body>
<body class='dark'>(all the content)</body>
```

- The change from one to the other is triggered by a switcher with a css class '.slider' on it, that gets called everytime it is clicked:

```
const switchBtn = document.querySelector('.slider');
switchBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
if(document.body.classList.contains('light')) {
        document.body.classList.replace('light', 'dark');
    }
    else
    {
        document.body.classList.replace('dark', 'light');
    };     
});
```

And until this point, everything changes from one to the other fine.

- At last, I added a way to try to store it locally by modifying/taking advantage (or that I thought) of the previous function:

```
let darkTheme = localStorage.getItem('dark');

switchBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    darkTheme = localStorage.getItem('dark'); //Trying update the info stored about the darkTheme    
    if(document.body.classList.contains('light') && darkTheme == null) {
        document.body.classList.replace('light', 'dark');
        localStorage.setItem('darkTheme', 'enabled');
    }
    else
    {
        document.body.classList.replace('dark', 'light');
        localStorage.setItem('darkTheme', null);
    };     
});
```

And at this point, I can see in Chrome's Application > Local Storage that every time I click, it does change the theme and it also changes the value of the key from 'enabled' to null and viceversa, but once I refresh the page, it returns to my 'light' theme, despite having the key still 'enabled'. In fact, at that point I can click to turn on the dark theme once again and, obviously, the value of the key remains the same; but if I click it again, as expected, it returns to the null value (light mode).

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Why do you use two different key names (`dark` and `darkTheme`) with local storage?

Comment: Hello, just a side note: multiple body elements are invalid (this is likely the reason why it's not working, as only the first body (or last body) tags will be considered - this will depend on the browser implementations), I'm sure I read it about somewhere in the W3C specs but can't find a direct source, so I apologize in advance.

Comment: @RobertMolina I'm sorry I did not clarify it enough, but there are not two body tags, it is just to show both classes I have, but in reality, it's only one body tag whose class changes from light to dark and viceversa, but thank you very much!

Comment: @HernánAlarcón In localStorage (if I'm not mistaken), I'm only registering one, which is 'darkTheme", whereas 'dark' is the class that I'm changing from my body tag, so I can switch it back and forth with the 'light' css class, but I may be mistaken :S

Comment: @HernánAlarcón I'm sorry! I see what you meant, at the very top I had a localStorage.getItem('dark') and the same goes with the first line after the function, where it should be localStorage.getItem('darkTheme'), but I changed both and it does not seem to work either :S

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because the actual changing is done only in the click event, you need to made an event that is called when page is loaded, and in that function, read from local storage and change css based on it. You don't event need an event, just cut or copy all the code in the click event function and paste it at the very end it the document (inside script tags of course)

Or better yet just call

switchBtn.dispatchEvent(new Event("click"))

Also having two body tags might be problematic I would recommend switching to div

Comment: I'm sorry I did not clarify it enough, but there are not two body tags, it is just to show both classes I have, but in reality, it's only one body tag whose class changes from light to dark and viceversa, but thank you very much! I added that last line of code and now it keeps returning to "dark" theme instead. The script is at the very end of the body tag using django's tag {% include 'scripts.html' %}. I will do my best to research that line of code you shared with me, as - due to my newbieness - I think I may not be implementing it properly. Once again, thank you :)

Comment: @victor I
Hi just try to make a new html file without any libraries, or if the click event doesn't work just copy all the button code to the bottom and see what happens